# pairwise variance comparisons with Fligner-Killeen tests and adjusted p-values

Tags: r

I am trying to compare variances in four groups. I need to know which variances differ significantly. I am not sure how to set up pairwise variance comparisons between all groups and then adjust the p-values with p.adjust='fdr'.

I have tried something like this but it does not seem to work...

```
# define function

my.fligner.test=function(df){
       my.fligner.test.results=fligner.test(magnitude~cycle,data=df) 

answer=data.frame(cycle=unique(df$cycle),
                my.stat=my.fligner.test.results$statistic,
                my.p.val=my.fligner.test.results$p.value)
return(answer)
}

# run tests

all.fligner.tests=with(myvariances,
                   by(myvariances, list(cycle),
                      function (x) my.fligner.test(x)))

# create a data frame...

all.fligner.tests=do.call(rbind, all.fligner.tests)
```

Here is my sample data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3rb9kdsx8aefxy6/myvariances.csv?dl=0

I would much appreciate a simple explanation.